# ASP.NET and JavaScript code working locally, but not on IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am having a hard time with my site created in Expression Web 4.0. All the fields connect to a SQL database and I have included a JavaScript code to calculate the value of some of the fields. The project works perfectly when using the Microsoft Visual Studio development server locally, but once I upload the site to IIS 7 server I can't seem to be able to run the JavaScript. The page does not return any error, but the calculations wont run.

I have tried running IE in compatibility mode, tried different browsers, and nothing. I have tried using an external JS file and same problem.

I debugged the issue with IE and Chrome and this is the error it encounters:
**"unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference"**

I have tried placing the JavaScript code before and after the Form, and same problem.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
function Calculate1(Served1) {


var Prepared1val = parseInt (document.getElementById("Prepared1").value);
var RTS1val = parseInt (document.getElementById("RTS1").value);
var Toss1val = parseInt (document.getElementById("Toss1").value);
Served1.value= Prepared1val - Toss1val - RTS1val;

 } 
 </script>
```

The debugger stops right after the first line of code and seems to not be able to find a value, even though it's there.

Comment: From where do you call the "Calculate" JS function in your code?  I have seen issues like this occur in production when everything working fine when testing locally b/c there is more latency involved with the content of the webpage coming across the network from the production server vs. local and the DOM may not be loaded yet when the javascript function is called.

Comment: I call it from the top of the page/code, I had also tried calling it from all the way of the bottom of the page. I have also tested it activating AutoPostBack for each of the textboxes involved, but no go.

Comment: There's not enough here to reproduce the problem.  Can you make a JSFiddle that fails in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making referenced to these elements: "Prepared1", "RTS1", "Toss1".  Make sure those element names are still available when you move the code - it's sounding like they are not.  ASP can change element IDs.

Comment: Insert this at the top of your function -- it's a start:  if (typeof (document.getElementById("Prepared1")) == 'undefined') alert('Prepared1 is not defined');

Answer (score 0):

What the error means is that the object reference the browser is trying to get the `value` property of is null.  If it occurs at the first line of code, it means that there is no element with id `Prepared1`.  Are you sure it's there?  Case matters in element ids.

If the problem is that your hard-coded ids don't match what's in the page, you should consider using the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Comment: Yes it's there. I hace checked it and even worked with the file in the server directly to make sure I'm previewing the same file. It is very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. Thanks for all trying to help. As Codenoire said, the ASP was changing the ID names and when it was being run it is adding "FormView" before the ID name. I solved half the issue, because it only works with IE and not with Chrome, in Chrome the ID's are renamed to something else, it is odd, but as long as it works with IE I am happy. Thank you again!